Wise men from the east...how many were they?
Growing up I came to know the wise men from the east who visited Jesus as three wise men. Does the scripture reveal if they were three?

No, there may have been three but the Bible doesn't say. People assumed there were three because three gifts were given. But it doesn't logically follow since three gifts were given then there are only three men.

BTW, welcome to BHSE. I hope you will hang out for awhile.

We are not told so we do not know.

Here is the complete passage referring to wise men or magi visiting Jesus.
The passage does not indicate the number of wise men.
Matthew chapter 2

1 Now after Jesus was born in Bethlehem of Judea in the days of Herod the king, behold, wise men from the east came to Jerusalem, 2 saying, “Where is he who has been born king of the Jews? For we saw his star when it rose and have come to worship him.” 3 When Herod the king heard this, he was troubled, and all Jerusalem with him; 4 and assembling all the chief priests and scribes of the people, he inquired of them where the Christ was to be born. 5 They told him, “In Bethlehem of Judea, for so it is written by the prophet:
6 “‘And you, O Bethlehem, in the land of Judah,
are by no means least among the rulers of Judah;
for from you shall come a ruler
who will shepherd my people Israel.’”
7 Then Herod summoned the wise men secretly and ascertained from them what time the star had appeared. 8 And he sent them to Bethlehem, saying, “Go and search diligently for the child, and when you have found him, bring me word, that I too may come and worship him.” 9 After listening to the king, they went on their way. And behold, the star that they had seen when it rose went before them until it came to rest over the place where the child was. 10 When they saw the star, they rejoiced exceedingly with great joy. 11 And going into the house, they saw the child with Mary his mother, and they fell down and worshiped him. Then, opening their treasures, they offered him gifts, gold and frankincense and myrrh. 12 And being warned in a dream not to return to Herod, they departed to their own country by another way.
13 Now when they had departed, behold, an angel of the Lord appeared to Joseph in a dream and said, “Rise, take the child and his mother, and flee to Egypt, and remain there until I tell you, for Herod is about to search for the child, to destroy him.”

Three things are listed as gifts given to Jesus in verse 11. We are not told if these are gift types with more than one gold, frankincense or myrrh item or if they were individual items. Some have suggested that since there were three gifts or gift types maybe there were three wise men.
It would be accurate to say that though we know how many gifts or gift types there were, we don't know for sure how many wise men there were.

Technically we know that there were three types of gifts, not three gifts. Some obscure traditions say there were twelve magi or even a large group, perhaps led by three. A gift of gold especially could have been a collective offering.

@DanFefferman  You are correct. We don't know if they were three gifts, three gift types, or how many people were offering. I'll update my answer - v11 "...opening their treasures, they offered him gifts, gold and frankincense and myrrh."
